# Split strings having special characters, also without double quotes

Tags: java, regex, string

I have been writing a web application functioning over keyword search. If the keyword contains special character(`,@#<$%` etc) i want to break the keyword into two, with and without special characters.

For example @apple, should be spitted into @apple and apple. But this should be done only if the string is not enclosed within double quotes.

For the keyword, `hello "@this" is just a #test`

i am expecting `hello "@this" is just a #test test`

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following and see -

```
String regex = "(?<!\")([,@#<$%]{1})(\\w+)(?!\")";
String input = "hello \"@this\" is just a #test";
System.out.println(input);
System.out.println(input.replaceAll(regex, "$0 $2"));
```

Output is

```
hello "@this" is just a #test
hello "@this" is just a #test test
```

Comment: It was much helpful. What should be done if i want open and close brackets between words with special characters.

In case of output like this,

hello "@this" is just a (#test test).

Is this possible?

Comment: Just change `"$0 $2"` to `"($0 $2)"`.

Comment: Sorry for adding much. I dint specify this in my question. The special characters may be in any position. But i want it to be spitted up anyway. Also the words within double quotes should not be affected (even if there are many words also if there any special character)

For example, "hi!, hello$ there" this# is just a %test

The output may be "hi!, hello$ there" this# this is just a %test test.

Does this make sense?

Comment: That's not a consistent pattern. I doubt that you could achieve that with just some simple regex replace. I might have to do some programming for that.

Comment: Could you help me on this?

Comment: Could you ask a new question with clear and accurate details?

Comment: yes. i asked the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577197/split-strings-with-special-characters-which-are-not-enclosed-with-double-quotes

Answer (score 0):

if there are any characters between `"` and `@`
like: `hello "stuff @this" is just a #test`

you may use this pattern : `[,@#<$%](?=(([^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)(\S+)`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nS3pW5)